# How to send keys to credit card fields( fields are from stripe) using selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, stripe-payments, selenium-chromedriver

I am automating few test cases related to payments. The payment page is integrated with Stripe.I have tried using the below cases:

- driver.findElement(By.id("cardNumber")).sendKeys("4242424242424242");
- driver.findElement(By.id("cardNumber")).sendKeys(Keys.NUMPAD4);// send keys one by one

Looks like selenium is sending the keys as a string and the card fields allow only integers.
Can anyone help me to overcome this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How would a user type an integer vs a string? You need to share more information about the page, preferably a link to the site.

Comment: For user, when you type numbers the field accepts.Any other key is not accepted. There is no validation on the front end like input tag having type=number.

Comment: That's not int vs string, that's numbers vs not numbers. Post a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Comment: Share the relevant HTML please.

Comment: You may be identifying the wrong element. Please share the link to the site for someone to be able to help you. I have tested on stripe documentation page and I am able to using `sendKeys` with complete card number to set the card number and it works

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

Have a string variable defining the card number

```
String cnum = "4242424242424242"
```

Then use a `for` loop to extract single character and use second pointer in your question, as below:

```
for (char ch : cnum.toCharArray()) {
    switch (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(ch))) {
        case 1:
            driver.findElement(By.id("cardNumber")).sendKeys(Keys.NUMPAD1);
            break;
        case 2:
            //and so on...
    }
}
```

Let us know if this helps you.